# Custom JavaScript through Chrome extension isn't hiding the LinkedIn feed

Tags: javascript

I'm using the custom js extension for running a js snippet on linkedin.com when it loads that hides the feed but it's not hiding the feed as expected.
The extension is:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk

And the code is:

```
function hideFeed() { 
$("#ember24").hide(); 
window.setTimeout(function(){hideFeed();}, 500);
}
hideFeed();
```

The developer console shows that ember24 is the id for the feed container.
[image]

The feed doesn't hide.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: I'm not sure if the extension errors are in the console. I see a "unidentified $". The feed doesn't hide with document.getElementById either.